# Jquery link and URL hash

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new at jQuery and don't really know what I'm doing.  I need some help.

I'm creating a web app.  It has a header and footer that I want to stay on every page, so I decided to use jQuery to load a page into the main content div so every time a link is clicked, the whole page isn't reloaded.

Here's what I'm using to accomplish this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("a.ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#main_content").fadeOut('fast');
            $("#main_content").load(this.href);
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
            $("#main_content").fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
  </script>
```

And each link:

```
<a class="ajax-link" id="add" href="add.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="margin-top:4px;"></span><div>add</div></a>
```

This works great EXCEPT the page address.  My app uses PHP, and I need to be able to PHP Header to a page like 'index.php#about' that will load the index.php page and display the about.php in the #main_content div.

I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var id = window.location.hash;
       $(id).trigger('click');
    })
  </script>
```

I can see where the link is selected (box around it), but it doesn't actually click it.  I'm not sure why.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Look into .children(), .removeClass(), .addClass()

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just get the hash, add a php extension and make an ajax call.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("a.ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the hash from the URL and append .php extension
            // index.php#about ==> 'about.php'

            var page = window.location.hash + ".php";

            //Make an ajax call using the page variable.

            $("#main_content").fadeOut('fast');
            $("#main_content").load(page);
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
            $("#main_content").fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I tried this, and it does the same thing as what it was doing before.  I can see a box around the link where it has been selected by the browser, but it has not been clicked.